# Alias subnetworks with Google Cloud IPSec VPN

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vpn, openvpn, ipsec, google-cloud-vpn

My company's infrastructure is hosted on Google Cloud. We'd like to connect a network of one our clients with site-to-site (IPSec) VPN. I've setup one on Google Cloud but we have a problem. Our subnetwork (10.10.0.0/16) is overlapping with their subnetworks (10.10.0.0/24). We have to solve this on our end, so on Google Cloud. Any idea how we can achieve this?

I tried to add a new subnet 192.168.64.0/24 to our VMs, The tunnel comes comes up.

But connectivity still fails. Traffic inbound and outbound failing

Comment: The quick and simple answer is that you cannot have overlapping networks. The expert answer is that there are tricks that can be used to handle overlapping networks in some cases but not all. This requires detailed knowledge of the routers, networks and address assignments. Your question is off-topic for Stackoverflow but there might be a better site to post on Stackexchange.

Comment: This question has been already asked - https://serverfault.com/questions/989268/overlapping-subnetworks-with-google-cloud-ipsec-vpn